# How to change attribute position (layered navigation) sorting based on category wise in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.3, layered-navigation

I want to change attribute position based on category page
means want to change custom position

here I have list of attribute

> size, color, amps, phase

for example
in category1 I want show color second number and size forth number in layed navigation
in category2 I want show color third number and size second number in navigation

I found code in vendor but no idea how to change it position based on above

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/FilterList.php
```

in this file have a function

```
public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
{
    if (!count($this->filters)) {
        $this->filters = [
            $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
        ];
        foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
            $this->filters[] = $this->createAttributeFilter($attribute, $layer);
        }
    }
    return $this->filters;
}
```

Thanks in advance.